# How to read a response from a web service that returns a byte[]

Tags: java, rest, byte, arrays

I've got this code of my web service:

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static Response fillData(final Map<String, Object> data, final   String name, @Context final ServletContext context) {  
       ...  
       final byte[] file = ...
       return Response.ok(file).build();
```

How can I read the response in my client?

```
final javax.ws.rs.core.Response reponse = client.target(URL_REST).path("/path").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
```

This is totally wrong (ByteArray doesn't exist), but I want to do something like it:

```
byte[] pdfByteArray = reponse.readEntity(ByteArray.class);
```

How can I do?

Comment: `byte[].class` exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like suggested Gabor above, I'll just use byte[].class
Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Use `java.io.InputStream`

```
InputStream is = reponse.readEntity(InputStream.class);
```

This allows you to read in a streaming way instead of reading all bytes at once.

Comment: so just to clarify the underlying implementation keeps the HTTP connection open until we call is.close()? Say we are streaming over a large file, which will only start to be streamed once we start reading from the stream (I assume the HTTP connection stays idle until we start reading?).

Comment: There's not necessarily a 1:1 correlation with `InputStream.close()`. The resulting stream may be a buffering one or the client may apply some optimizations. In any case, closing the stream is mandatory for proper resource management.